Second order statistics of sample statistics for random vectors
Good morning.
I have a set of iid random vectors $\{\boldsymbol{X}^i\}_{i=1}^N$, whose expected value is $\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{X}^i] = \boldsymbol{\mu}$ and whose variance - covariance matrix is $\boldsymbol{\sigma} = \mathrm{Var}(\boldsymbol{X}^i)$. Define the sample statistics
$$\overline{\boldsymbol{X}}_N = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \boldsymbol{X}^i$$
and
$$\boldsymbol{S}_N = \frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^N \left(\boldsymbol{X}^i - \overline{\boldsymbol{X}}_N\right) \otimes \left(\boldsymbol{X}^i - \overline{\boldsymbol{X}}_N\right) $$
I know the results
$$\mathbb{E}[\overline{\boldsymbol{X}}_N] = \boldsymbol{\mu}$$
$$\mathrm{Var}(\overline{\boldsymbol{X}}_N) = \frac{1}{N}\boldsymbol{\sigma}$$
Also, I know that
$$\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{S}_N] = \boldsymbol{\sigma}$$
What is the general result (that is, without the normality or independence assumption) for the variance of $\boldsymbol{S}_N$? I know that $\boldsymbol{S}_N$ is a matrix, so for me if $\boldsymbol{S} = (S_{ij})$, it would be enough to have the values od $\mathrm{Var}(S_{ij})$.
I would be pleased if you could give me a reference for citing these results.
Thank you.

There is no general result because it depends on third and fourth moments of the distribution.  A simple example of the calculation that reveals how these moments emerge is given in my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/654947/919.

You are right. I should have added to the hypothesis the third and fourth order moments as known data, but I have not included them as I am not sure which ones are necessary and the tensorial character grows...
Is there a general expression involving this third and fourth order moments?

Yes: apply the formula and expand, as illustrated in the link I provided.  The expansion grows long and messy, because the fourth-order moments form a rank-four tensor (with four indices) having on the order of $n^4$ coefficients.

Indeed, I was asking because I didn't want to expand all of this stuff ... I expected that there was a "common"formula already been calculated by someone in a textbook ... I am sure that I am going to miss something in the computations if I do it by myself...
Thank you anyway!

Is there at least a simplified formula for the uncorrelated case, that is, Cov(X_1,X_2) = 0, involving up to 4-th order moments?

Although it simplifies a little, it still requires third and fourth moments and that information is not determined by second moments alone.

I know. Ok. Let us assume thay we know the components of the tensors:
\mu_i = E[X_i]
\sigma_{ij} = E[X_iX_j] - E[X_i]E[X_j]
\delta_{ijk} = E[X_iX_jX_k]
\gamma_{ijkl} = E[X_iX_jX_kX_l]
What is the most general expression for the correlated case (I know it is a mess, but is it anywhere?)
